# Kerberos authentication on Mac - SQL Server, Azure Data Studio

Tags: macos, authentication, kerberos

I'm working through a .NET6 tutorial on my Macbook Pro (M1) Ventura OS (13.3.1). Im running a SQL Server image on Docker and have been able to connect to the database with Azure Data Studio. Im doing the code first approach when creating my database. Ive successfully made a model and added a migration using the dotnet CLI. When I attempt to create the SQL database by running `dotnet ef database update` from Visual Studio terminal I get the following error:

`Cannot authenticate using Kerberos. Ensure Kerberos has been initialized on the client with 'kinit' and a Service Principal Name has been registered for the SQL Server to allow Kerberos authentication.`
`ErrorCode=InternalError, Exception=Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested (unknown mech-code 0 for mech unknown).`
`at`[`System.Net`](http://system.net/)`.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.GssInitSecurityContext(SafeGssContextHandle& context, SafeGssCredHandle credential, Boolean isNtlm, SafeGssNameHandle targetName, GssFlags inFlags, Byte[] buffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, UInt32& outFlags, Int32& isNtlmUsed)`
`at`[`System.Net`](http://system.net/)`.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext(SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, String targetName, ContextFlagsPal inFlags, SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, ContextFlagsPal& outFlags)`
 `at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext(SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, Byte[] receivedBuff, Byte[]& sendBuff, Byte[][] serverName)`
 `at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext(Byte[] receivedBuff, UInt32 receivedLength, Byte[]& sendBuff, UInt32& sendLength, Byte[][] _sniSpnBuffer)`
 `at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData(Byte[] receivedBuff, UInt32 receivedLength, Byte[]& sendBuff, UInt32& sendLength)`

I’ve done multiple iterations of kinit and keep getting this message of unable to connect
`sbaqla@Saras-MacBook-Pro ~ % kinit`
`sbaqla@ATTLOCAL.NET``'s password:` 
`kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: unable to reach any KDC in realm` [`ATTLOCAL.NET`](http://attlocal.net/)`, tried 0 KDCs`

I tried my computer pw, windows pw (the one i used to create an account for docker) and no password. Ive tried to change my kerberos password through Utilities -> Keychain Access -> Ticket Viewer. but it tells me incorrect password. (go figure) I downloaded Keberos Ticket Autorenewal app but get the following message when I try to add credentials:
`The operation couldn't be completed. (org.h5l.GSS error 851968 - unable to reach any KDC in realm ATTLOCAL.NET, tried 0 KDCs)`

my k4b5.conf file looks like this:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = ATTLOCAL.NET
 
[realms]
ATTLOCAL.NET = {
   kdc = dc-33.attlocal.net
}
```

Main docs Ive referred to have been:
Configuring KDC for Mac: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15

Blog: connecting to SQL Server: https://medium.com/@chriskuchar/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-from-a-mac-with-windows-authentication-44375ec1953e

Windows Authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15